# Allow Samba connections *only* from internal LAN (PF firewall)?

Tags: networking, firewall, samba, freebsd, pf

There is a FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE machine with only 1 NIC, serving Samba shares behind a [PF firewall](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) on **same** server.

I need to allow connections **only** from clients connecting from the internal network (/24).

Currently this would seem to work:

```
# Default deny policy
block in log all

# allow Samba connections only from internal IPs
pass in quick on $ext_if inet proto tcp from $ext_if:network to $ext_if:network port {135, 137, 138, 139, 445}
pass in quick on $ext_if inet proto udp from $ext_if:network to $ext_if:network port {135, 137, 138, 139, 445}
```

Are these proper and enough, though?

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to allow Samba connections only from internal LAN using PF firewall?

Comment: Are you using vlans with pfsense? As this would be the easiest way to control internal traffic between two lans you control. Two separate interfaces would do the same.

Comment: No, the server runs on stock FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE, with no vlan compiled in kernel. Also, it has only one interface.

Comment: I'm confused, how are you routing anything without two interfaces? Default Ethernet behavior will allow any connection through the lan switch. I.e if the samba share is on the same local segment, how do you expect pfsense to block traffic it has no control over?

Comment: I tried to clarify question: PF is OpenBSD Packet Filter (not pfsense, which is based on it), and the firewall resides on same machine as the samba shares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another interface to your pf-sense installation. or if a VLAN capable switch is available it will give you additional virtual interfaces in pf-sense.

you would put your samba share on a second interface give it a new Subnet (something like 10.10.10.0 /24) anything will work you just need it to be a different subnet from the lan users you want to control.

now set up rules for what users can access the second LAN Subnet. or specifically what users have access to your samba share by ip.

EDIT: in PF (Filtering) to do this:
after a default block rule >

Traffic must now be explicitly passed through the firewall or it will be dropped by the default deny policy. This is where packet criteria such as source/destination port, source/destination address and protocol come into play. Whenever traffic is permitted to pass through the firewall, the rule(s) should be written to be as restrictive as possible. This is to ensure that the intended traffic, and only the intended traffic, is permitted to pass.

"# Pass traffic in on dc0 from the local network, 192.168.0.0/24, to OpenBSD"

"# machine's IP address 192.168.0.1. Also, pass the return traffic out on dc0."

pass in  on dc0 from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.0.1

pass out on dc0 from 192.168.0.1    to 192.168.0.0/24

"#Pass TCP traffic in to the web server running on the OpenBSD machine."

pass in on egress proto tcp from any to egress port www

use your interface name, add your sub-nets in and you should be good to go, use the ip rules. it will make this much easier.

I only see two pass rules in your post, I believe you would need an in/out with both tcp and udp.

Comment: Thank you. I added detail to question, the server has only 1 NIC, also, PF (not pfsense) is running from same server as samba shares. Is there any way to have same protection without adding a second NIC?

Comment: i updated your answer, i left the PFsense answer in because its a common question to PF in general. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help